# How can I exclude multiple users from Get-ADuser cmdlet output in powershell?

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory

I am trying export a list of all users in a specific office for an external guest check-in system. Except some users (about 20 or so) are not to be added to the public directory, and I need them excluded from the output.

Here's what I have so far...

```
    Get-ADUser -Filter {City -eq "Dallas"} -Properties GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Name |
        Select GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Name | 
        Sort-Object -Property GivenName | 
        Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ADusers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

I am hoping to avoid a long filter line for example...

```
-filer {(name -ne "name 1")(name -ne "name 2")...} etc
```

Ideally, I would like to create a variable listing the specified users. That way I can easily modify later.

```
    $excluded = "Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","Name 4"
```

Results are as expected (except for the users that need to be excluded)...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do the AD records for the users to be excluded have any common factor that is not shared by the other users? Or, contrariwise, do they lack any common factor that _is_ shared by the other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there isn't a custom attribute or other way to identify these users / set them apart in ActiveDirectory already the one thing you could do is build the filter string from your name array

```
$excluded = "Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","Name 4"
$namefilter = ($excluded | ForEach-Object{"name -ne '$_'"}) -join " -and " 
$cityfilter = "City -eq 'Dallas'"
Get-ADUser -Filter ($cityfilter, $namefilter -join " -and ") -Properties GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Name
```

So the filter would effectively be this:

```
City -eq 'Dallas' -and name -ne 'Name 1' -and name -ne 'Name 2' -and name -ne 'Name 3' -and name -ne 'Name 4'
```

It might seem convoluted but `$cityfilter, $namefilter -join " -and "` allows for one of those filters to be missing without code changes. So if the `$excluded` ended up being empty the code would still succeed. You could easily simply this but it was something I thought of mitigating.

Comment: Very well thought out! Thank you